# scikit learn Type error only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I get the following error on the call to cosine_similarity

```
numerator = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x,y))
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I am trying to get a keyword-keyword co-occurrence matrix from the document-keyword matrix returned by CountVectorizer.

I feel there is something that `cosine_similarity` doesn't like about the data type I am passing it, but I am not sure what exactly the issue is. Here, `n` is of type `scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix` and `y` is of type `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

```
documents = (
    "The sky is blue",
    "The sun is bright",
    "The sun in the sky is bright",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun"
)

countvectorizer = CountVectorizer()
y =  countvectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
n  = y.T.dot(y) 
x = n.tocsr()
x = x.toarray()
numpy.fill_diagonal(x, 0) 

result = cosine_similarity(x, "None")
```

Comment: First guess would be the sparse representation causing problems, have you tried converting the matrices to the non-sparse representation?

Comment: @ncfirth By non-sparse you mean to  numpy array?

Comment: Yeah [more characters]

Comment: @ncfirth Hi.. but that's what I do after the dot product operation (convert the matrix to an array using toarray())

Comment: Could you give some example data to work with?

Comment: @ncfirth Added some example data, thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this must be a problem with the `cosine_similarity` function that you're using. See the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sklearn` `cosine_similarity` this code segment runs and returns a sensible looking answer.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import distance_metrics

documents = (
    "The sky is blue",
    "The sun is bright",
    "The sun in the sky is bright",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun"
)

countvectorizer = CountVectorizer()
y =  countvectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
n  = y.T.dot(y) 
x = n.tocsr()
x = x.toarray()
np.fill_diagonal(x, 0) 
cosine_similarity = distance_metrics()['cosine']
result = cosine_similarity(x, x)
```